# Cannot view GDrive in moodle using iOS

Tags: html, ios, iframe, moodle

This is the iframe code that I use to embedded in Moodle, it can be viewed in Android but not to iOS. How to solved this?
`<p><iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1d-SHXhof2KnyTmMr2GowJuf4bVKFKQg3&amp;usp#list" width="100%" height="900" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>`
Thank you in advance

Comment: It says "You need access"... maybe you need to make it Viewable by anyone with the link?

Comment: it is still same if i put it as public

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling **cross-site tracking prevention** on you IOS device under **Safari** > **Preferences** > **Privacy**.

Comment: Hi Themodmin, 

I have try to disable it, but the result is still the same.